# Is the language given by this CFG regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free

```
 S → AB | C
 A → aAb | ab
 B → cBd | cd
 C → aCd | aDd
 D → bDc | bc
```

How can I prove that this language is regular or not? I need your help. It also has two leftmost derivations. Does this help me to prove it?

Comment: So, what language is generated? This would be a start in answering your question.

Comment: Please see our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions). The formal languages section should contain most of what you need. If it doesn't, please ask a more specific question about the part where you got stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by: "It also has two leftmost derivations". That is something you say of a word in the language, not of the language itself. What will help you is the first comment you received. Then the second one will help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language denoted by your grammar is:

$L=\{a^nb^nc^md^m | n\geq 1,m \geq 1\}\cup \{a^nb^mc^md^n | n\geq 1,m \geq 1\}$

Hint: You can prove that this language is not regular using the pumping lemma.

Spoiler alert:

> Use the word $\sigma= a^Nb^Mc^Md^N$ with $N\neq M$ and $K=N+M$ your pumping lemma constant.

Comment: You have a typo in your definiton of $L$.

Comment: I edited the definition. If it is still incorrect feel free too edit my answer if you want.

Comment: Sorry, actually it was fine .. my eyesight is not. The last exponent $n$ is so closed to the $d$ in $d^n$ that the vertical bar of the $d$ made it look like an $m$. Hope you did not spend too much time on this. Next time [**:)**], I will be more precise, so that it is clear when I am wrong.